# Phalcon install give error on ubuntu

Tags: phalcon

I'm trying to install phalcon in my ubuntu 14.04 by using below commands

> git clone https://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
>
> cd cphalcon/build
>
> sudo ./install

and it give a error like this

```
/usr/include/php5/ext/pcre/php_pcre.h:29:18: fatal error: pcre.h: No such file or directory
#include "pcre.h"
              ^
compilation terminated.
```

then i google the error and found solution as installing

> sudo apt-get install libpcre3-dev

when i try to do that it give error like this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libpcre3-dev : Depends: libpcre3 (= 1:8.31-2ubuntu2) but 1:8.31-       2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
            Depends: libpcrecpp0 (= 1:8.31-2ubuntu2) but 1:8.31-2ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

pleas help me with this...

Comment: like i said i tried but it's give the second error.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get build-dep libpcre3-dev`

Comment: Same error here. The above command @M2sh not solves the error.